# Pojo class with variable field

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a pojo class for recyclerview.

The data I am getting from the json will be like this.

```
newsfeeddata:{ id:"",
  timestamp:"",
  userdetails:{
     id:""
     profile_pic_url:"",
     name:""
  },
  post:{ (optional)
    id:""
    text:"" 
  },
  media :{ (optional)
    id:""
    url:""
  }
}
```

In some objects there will be 'post' and in other object instead of 'post' there will be 'media'. How do I make a pojo class for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make separate classes for `userdetails`, `post` and `media`. And use them as instance variable in `newsfeeddata` class.

```
public class Post {
    public String id;
    public String text;
}

public class Userdetails {
    public String id;
    public String profile_pic_url;
    public String name;
}

public class Media {
    public String id;
    public String url;
}
```

Now use an instance of these in your `newsfeeddata` class.

```
public class Newsfeeddata {

    public String id;
    public String timestamp;
    public Userdetails userdetails;
    public Post post;
    public Media media;

}
```

Note:

1. You can change the access-modifier to private and use getters and setters. Read about lombook-data annotation. Using a single `@Data` annotation above your class, you can have all getters, setters, toString implementation and more. Makes your class concise and pretty.
2. You may want to change data-type of fields. For simplicity, I have used `String`.

Comment: check out http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. This helps to quickly generate pojo from json.